# How can I remove outliers if I have the following datatypes?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

[The image is the screenshot taken from the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFETG.jpg)
I have executed label encoder on the column ['Sex', 'Embarked'] and converted their datatype to object.
I have applied yeo-johnson technique to transform skewness into normal distribution.
How can I remove outliers as well as scale the data? I'm getting attribute error saying >`numpy.ndarray has no attribute shape`

I have dataset of shape(891,8)

> columns:            Dtypes

```
1. Survived         int64
2. Pclass           int64
3. Sex              object
4. Age              float64
5. SibSp            int64
6. Parch            int64
7. Fare             float
8. Embarked        object
```

> dt.skew()

```
Survived    0.478523
Pclass     -0.630548
Sex        -0.618921
Age         0.509545
SibSp       3.695352
Parch       2.749117
Fare        4.787317
Embarked   -1.264823
```

> x= dt.drop('Survived',axis=1)
> y=dt['Survived']

> applying powertransformer for normal distribution

```
pt = PowerTransformer()
x1 = pt.fit_transform(x)
```

Comment: you better type in runnable code here, not just a screenshot. this will help ppl who can help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.